# Stop Postback in Image Button after validation failed

Tags: asp.net

I have a aspx page containing a text box and an image button for search. I have used compare validator (to check for integer values) with the textbox. But the page reloads on the image button click even if I enter alphanumeric characters, along with showing the error message.

I tried using a regularexpressionvalidator instead but the problem persists.

But when i used a simple asp:button instead and binded it with textbox validation, its working fine (i.e. postback does not occur on incorrect value of textbox) and same is true with dropdownlist also (no postback occuring).

Please suggest.

Here's the code-

@peroija : Here's the code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" 
    ToolTip="Search" ValidationGroup="valControl" CausesValidation="true" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWidth" CssClass="TextFont" runat="server" 
    Width="233px" MaxLength="20" 
    ValidationGroup="valControl" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="cmpValWidth" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter integer values" ControlToValidate="txtWidth" Display="Dynamic" 
    Operator="DataTypeCheck" ValidationGroup="valControl"Type="Integer"/>
```

Comment: can you post the code for your textbox, image button, and compare validator? it sounds like you may have assigned one of them but not the other a validation group

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to write

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
```

> "your code"

```
}
```

in the code behind. To prevent the code from being run if the page is not viewed for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your textbox, you only need it on the validator and the button:

```
ValidationGroup="valControl" CausesValidation="true"
```

If javascript is disabled, then there will be no client side validation, so always check the validity on the server side also:

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    "your btnSearch_Click code"
}
```

Comment: I tried without ValidationGroup="valControl" CausesValidation="true"
on textbox but no use... I tried checking validation with simple asp:button and even with a drop down (when selected index is changed) then its working fine.. its creating problem with this image button.

Comment: @MeghaGupta does your image button have any client side code (check in the page source, or with browser developer tools) - post it here if it does, but basically it must **not** have any `return` statements...

Comment: yup it has some client side.. basically validating data in other controls like text box etc through javascript and returning true/false depending on successful validation or not respectively.. How does any return stmt in client code matter?

Comment: @MeghaGupta default asp.net validation does not have any return statements in the `onclick` event, so you probably added an "Are you sure?" prompt window, or something else that has a return statement before the validation code, effectively making it completely unreachable...

Comment: thanks for your reply.. the problem was (as u mentioned) that there is a return statement in the client side code which wz getting executed on the button click event causing the postback. Any client side code will always get executed irrespective of any other asp.net validation. And if there is a return stmt like "return true" it will alwayz cause the postback.
Thanks :)

Comment: @MeghaGupta post your code if you want any further help, otherwise don't forget to accept the answer...